# CouchDB Filtered Replication not working

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am using `PouchDB` on client side and `CouchDB` on server side. My client need to replicate data from the server using a filter.

Here is the client code I am using:

```
_db.replicate.from(_remote_db, {
                filter: "repl/myfilter",
                live: false,
                retry: true,
                query_params: {
                    group: '11'
                }
            }).on('change', (info) => {
                dbReplChangeHandler(_db, _db_analytics, info, deferred);
            })
```

While the design document in the `couchDB` database is :

```
   {
  "_id": "_design/repl",
  "_rev": "19-3848f574d651345540379c06b67699bb",
  "filters": {
    "myfilter": "function (doc, req){return true;}"
  }
}
```

The client is still not able to replicate from the server throwing this error `timeout,{gen_server,call,\n                     [couch_proc_manager,}`

Comment: Please, could you complete the error trace? Also, you can check if GET /db/_changes?filter=repl/myfilter is working.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with couchdb 2.1.1 (I confirmed this behavior on a Mac, don't know if it exist on other platforms). Is quite simple to reproduce:

1) Create a test database

```
curl -vX PUT http://localhost/testdb
```

2) Populate with documents

```
for i in {1..5}; do curl -vX PUT http://localhost/testdb/00$i -d '{"type":"A", "description":"Document 00$i"}'; done;
```

3) Test that you can see the documents

```
curl -X GET http://localhost/testdb/_changes?since=0
```

You'll see an output similar to the following:

```
{"results":[
{"seq":"3-g1AAAAB5eJzLYWBgYMpgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXLIyU9OzMnILy7JAUklMiTV____PyuDOZE5FyjAnmiWlmhuaIhNAx5j8liAJEMDkPoPMi2RIQsAx5cmmw","id":"001","changes":[{"rev":"3-c9fb50f5d39cdac66a342dfac914fc52"}]},
{"seq":"4-g1AAAAB5eJzLYWBgYMpgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXLIyU9OzMnILy7JAUklMiTV____PyuDOZElFyjAnmiWlmhuaIhNAx5j8liAJEMDkPoPMi2RIQsAx-UmnA","id":"004","changes":[{"rev":"1-987569f1cc05eaf1bad8793d290adab2"}]},
{"seq":"5-g1AAAAB5eJzLYWBgYMpgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXLIyU9OzMnILy7JAUklMiTV____PyuDOZE1FyjAnmiWlmhuaIhNAx5j8liAJEMDkPoPMi2RIQsAyDMmnQ","id":"005","changes":[{"rev":"1-987569f1cc05eaf1bad8793d290adab2"}]},
{"seq":"7-g1AAAACbeJzLYWBgYMpgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXLIyU9OzMnILy7JAUklMiTV____PyuDOZE1FyjAnmiWlmhuaIhNAx5j8liAJEMDkPoPNY0JbFqaoVGSobkxNn1ZAHN1MJo","id":"002","changes":[{"rev":"1-987569f1cc05eaf1bad8793d290adab2"}]},
{"seq":"8-g1AAAACbeJzLYWBgYMpgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXLIyU9OzMnILy7JAUklMiTV____PyuDOZE1FyjAnmiWlmhuaIhNAx5j8liAJEMDkPoPNY0ZbFqaoVGSobkxNn1ZAHOXMJs","id":"003","changes":[{"rev":"1-987569f1cc05eaf1bad8793d290adab2"}]},
"last_seq":"9-g1AAAACbeJzLYWBgYMpgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXLIyU9OzMnILy7JAUklMiTV____PyuDOZE1FyjAnmiWlmhuaIhNAx5j8liAJEMDkPoPNY0FbFqaoVGSobkxNn1ZAHO5MJw","pending":0}
```

4) Create a simple 'accept all' filter

```
curl -vX PUT http://localhost/testdb/_design/test -d '{"filters":{"everything":"function(doc, req){return true;}"}}'
```

5) Apply the filter to the _changes command

```
curl -X GET http://localhost/testdb/_changes?filter=test/everything&since=0
```

Now you will see something like this:

```
{
    "error": "error",
    "reason": "{timeout,{gen_server,call,
               [couch_proc_manager,
        {get_proc,{doc,<<\"_design/test\">>,
{1,
[<<251,118,3,66,28,132,147,60,168,234,
101,119,87,97,205,255>>]},
{[{<<\"filters\">>,
{[{<<\"everything\">>,
<<\"function(doc, req){return true;}\">>}]}}]},
],false,[]},
{<<\"_design/test\">>,
<<\"1-fb7603421c84933ca8ea65775761cdff\">>}},
5000]}}"
}
```

This is with version 2.1.1, I've confirmed that the version 2.1.1-1 (not released yet) works (at least for this case), which you can find [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/couchdb/binary/mac/2.1.1/).

If your problem happens on windows or linux, you might want to downgrade to version 2.1.0 or 2.0.

Hope this helps